# Error when I try to log in to MySQL server managment studio 2005?

Tags: sql-server

I try to log in to MySQL server managment studio 2005 using windows authentication but the following error is raised:

> ===================================
>
> Cannot connect to .\MSSQLSERVER.
>
> ===================================
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid) (.Net
>   SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> ------------------------------ For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=87&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ Error Number: 87 Severity: 20 State: 0
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean
>   ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean
>   trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, SqlConnection
>   owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64
>   timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String
>   host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance,
>   SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   Int64 timerStart)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection
>   owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String
>   newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo,
>   String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,
>   DbConnection owningConnection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ObjectExplorer.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo
>   ci, IServerType server)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()

Answer (score 1):

If it's the default instance, try connecting to just "." and ditch the \MSSQLSERVER. Otherwise, ensure the instance name really is "MSSQLSERVER" and that it's running and listening for network connections on the port you are trying to connect to.

Comment: when I use "." it is connected, but when i debug the application the same error raise in the code :S

Answer (score 0):

From reading the comments in the other posted answer, it sounds as though your application connection is using different settings to those that you are specifying when using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

1. Can you clarify if you have installed a default or named instance of SQL Server for us all please?
2. It may also help if you could share details of the connection string that you are using.

It's difficult to provide a definitive answer to your question from the limited information  provided thus far however:

- If you are using a default instance then you should be a able to establish a connection using the machine name or IP Address of the relevant server.
- If connecting to a named instance then you should be able to connect using the format "servername\instanceName".